# Getting error while set up email to friend using Ruby on Rail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody please help me for resolving this problem.I want to setup a email service in my webpage using ROR. when i typed the command "rails generate mailer userMailer" in my command propmpt i got the following error.

I am using rails-4 and ruby-1.9.3

```
Error:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.1.7/lib/action_mailer/base.rb
:553:in `method_missing': undefined method `server_settings=' for ActionMailer::
Base:Class (NoMethodError)
        from c:/Site/emailid1/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:276:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/comman
ds/commands_tasks.rb:147:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/comman
ds/commands_tasks.rb:133:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/comman
ds/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/comman
ds/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have already set up my environment.rb file inside config/environment.rb with the following code.

```
 ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.server_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.tutorialspoint.com",
   :port => 25,
   :domain => "http://localhost:3000",
   :authentication => :login,
   :user_name => "w5call.w5rtc@gmail.com",
   :password => "w5rtc123@",
}
ActionMailer::Base.default_content_type = "text/plain"
```

I am testing in localhost please help me to check above each hash value setting if anything wrong please,provide the right one and resolve the above error.

Comment: change it to `smtp_settings` instead of `server_settings`

Answer (score 0):

1: The article you are following is too old 
[tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm)
Use this snipped

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
 :port                 => 587,  
 :domain               => "gmail.com",  
 :user_name            => "email@gmail.com",  
 :password             => "*************",  
 :authentication       => "plain"
```

}

2: http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3?view=asciicast

Comment: For easy debugging on development, use the mailcatcher gem